#  canonical bundle of Abelian surface fibrations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, complex-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

For minimal surfaces admitting an elliptic fibration over a smooth curve,
there is a famous analysis of possible singular fibers and a canonical bundle formula due to Kodaira.

There are two papers of Kenji Ueno, in which he tries to classify the singular fibers of an abelian surface fibration over a smooth curve. But I don't see any formula for the canonical bundle of such threefolds?

Does any body know of any formula for that?

(All the varieties I am talking about are projective)

Comment: Koll\'ar wrote a chapter on canonical bundle formulas for fibrations of relative Kodaira dimension 0 in the book "Flips for 3-folds and 4-folds". It's quite technical, but maybe the results simplify in the case you're interested in...

Comment: @Mohammad F.Tehrani: What's the formula for the canonical bundle in the case of elliptic fibrations

Comment: @jlk: It is a pull back of some rational divisor from base. see Griffiths-Harris.